# Livewire component vanish after emitting event

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I made chat app using livewire, and i want to emit an event where in that event emitting antohter event to another component, but when i emit the event the component it self vanish from view, and i dont know why here is my code

```
<div class="flex flex-row py-2 px-2 items-center border-b-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100" wire:click="$emit('chatUserSelected',{{$conversation}})">
```

and the event in chatlist component

```
protected $listeners = ['chatUserSelected'];
public $conversations;
public $selectedConversation;


public function chatUserSelected(Conversation $conversation)
{
    
    $this->selectedConversation = $conversation;
    $receiverInstance = KontakModel::find($conversation->kontak_id);
    $this->emitTo('chat.chat-box','loadConversation',$this->selectedConversation,$receiverInstance);
     $this->emitTo('chat.send-message','updateSendMessage',$this->selectedConversation,$receiverInstance);
    
}

public function mount()
{
    $this->auth_id = auth()->id();
    $this->conversations = Conversation::orderBy('last_time_message','DESC')->where('solved_at',NULL)->get();
    // dd($this->conversations);
}
public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.chat.chat-list', );
}
```

here is my view before emitting event

[image: before]

and after emitting event

[image: after]

the chatlist somehow disappear

for additional this is code for my main view

```
<div class="flex flex-row justify-between bg-white h-screen" x-data="chatApp">
  @livewire('chat.chat-list')
  @livewire('admin.side-bar')
  <!-- message -->
  @livewire('chat.chat-box')
  <!-- end message -->
</div>
```

**chat.chat-list.blade.php**

```
<div class="overflow-y-auto">
    @forelse ($conversations as $conversation)
    <div class="flex flex-row py-2 px-2 items-center border-b-2 cursor-pointer hover:bg-gray-100" wire:key="{{$conversation->id}}" wire:click="$emit('chatUserSelected',{{$conversation}})">
        <div class="w-1/4">
        <img
            src="https://source.unsplash.com/otT2199XwI8/600x600"
            class="object-cover h-12 w-12 rounded-full"
            alt=""
        />
        </div>
        <div class="w-full">
        <div class="text-lg font-semibold">{{ $conversation->kontak->name }}</div>
        <span class="text-gray-500">{{$conversation->messages->sortBy('created_at')->last()->body}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="w-2/12">
        @php
            $unread = $conversation->messages->where('status', NULL)->where('category','receive')->count()
        @endphp
        @if ($unread > 0)
            <div class="text-sm text-center font-light rounded-full bg-red-600 text-white min-w-5 h-5">{{$unread}}</div>
        @endif
        <span class="text-xs">{{$conversation->messages->sortBy('created_at')->last()->created_at->shortAbsoluteDiffForHumans()}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    @empty
    <div class="flex flex-row py-2 px-2 items-center border-b-2 text-2xl text-center">
        <div class="text-center m-auto">
        No Conversation
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforelse
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the view code for your chat-list component?

Comment: @Peppermintology this is [chat-list](https://paste.ec/paste/V-h7JwUK#1kNLdmF8GAiQODymJi04qwVrr8yT9M4ZKEMWTkmR2z8)